# Channel Preferences : Email Address of notification recipients

Tags: channel-entries, channel-form

Is there a way I can set this dynamically?

I have users submitting channel entries from the front end via a Channel Form. I would like to route the notification email to a recipient the user chooses from one of the form fields.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm sure it can be done under the notification settings.

Comment: I used this plugin : https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster